# Get Custom FontResolver to include standard / installed fonts

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, pdfsharp

**Context**

In my C# app I am using PDFsharp to create custom PDF documents. I have to use some custom fonts that are not installed on the system beforehand, but instead are available through a resource file as a byte array. The easiest way to achieve that seems to be to use a custom Font Resolver that loads those fonts in the GetFont function. However, once I am implementing my own logic for GetFont, I am no longer able to use any other, standard fonts like Verdana, that are not explicitly loaded in GetFont.

**Code**

The following code is a simplified version of the code I am using right now.

```cs
    public class CustomFontResolver : IFontResolver
    {
        public string DefaultFontName => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public byte[] GetFont(string faceName)
        {
            switch (faceName)
            {
                case "MyCustomFont":
                    return Resources.MY_CUSTOM_FONT;
            }

            // This is the part where I would implement the "standard font loading"-logic

            return null;
        }

        public FontResolverInfo ResolveTypeface(string familyName, bool isBold, bool isItalic)
        {
            if(familyName.Equals("MyCustomFont", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                return new FontResolverInfo("MyCustomFont");
            }

            return PlatformFontResolver.ResolveTypeface(familyName, isBold, isItalic);
        }
    }
```

This means that, after setting `GlobalFontSettings.FontResolver = new CustomFontResolver();` the following line will work with no problems:

```cs
var font = new XFont("MyCustomFont", 20, XFontStyle.Regular);
```

But loading standard fonts like Verdana will fail with an exception, because my GetFont-function returns null for it:

```cs
var font = new XFont("Verdana", 20, XFontStyle.Regular);
```

**Question**

How can I load standard / already installed fonts as a byte array in my code, or modify the FontResolver in another way to take care of those fonts itself?

I tried using other ways than writing a custom font resolver before, but that did not work out, as PDFsharp does not allow adding fonts to its standard resolver.

I also looked for ways to load fonts and convert them to byte arrays, but could not find any.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is embarrassing to admit, the problem seems to be caused by a wrong package. Instead of the actual PdfSharp package I used PdfSharpCore, where `PlatformFontResolver.ResolveTypeface(familyName, isBold, isItalic)` returned `null`. This lead to the thrown exception, and not the implementation of GetFont. Using PdfSharp instead of the Core version everything works well now.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the default behaviour of the GDI build and the WPF build when using the "original" PDFsharp packages published by PDFsharp-Team. You already found out about that.

PdfSharpCore is a port that also works under Linux and other platforms, but does not automatically include platform-specific fonts.

Answer (score 0):

The [source of PdfSharp](https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp/blob/3205bd933b464d150c0f42e8bcdff3314b6c6164/src/PdfSharp/Fonts/FontFactory.cs#L149) has a if statement that checks if the `GlobalFontSettings.FontResolver` is set. If not, it will fall back to its own platform dependent implementation.

What you should do, is in your

```
// This is the part where I would implement the "standard font loading"-logic
```

Call the [same fall back method](https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp/blob/3205bd933b464d150c0f42e8bcdff3314b6c6164/src/PdfSharp/Fonts/PlatformFontResolver.cs#L66):

```
PlatformFontResolver.ResolveTypeface(string familyName, bool isBold, bool isItalic)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The fallback method could not have been used in GetBytes as you suggested, because it does not return a byte Array but a FontResolverInfo. Instead I have already been using it in the custom ResolveTypeface method, as shown in the code above. But this fallback method ended up being the problematic part, so thank you for guiding my focus onto that with your answer! (See my own answer for context)